# How can I configure the path to the Git executable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

How do I configure the path to the Git executable in Android Studio?

I am working in Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 48):

Paste this in a terminal:

```
whereis git
```

or if you get 'command not found' you can try

```
where git
```

You get the path to your Git executable.

Comment: it works. You have to separate the words : "where is git"

Answer (score 19):

I have done it for Windows 7. Probably you can refer this.

1. Download the GitHub For Windows client and install it.
2. After the client successfully installed, connect it with your GitHub account. It should be easy; just follow the wizard.
3. Then you should add the git.exe location to your "path variable": Otherwise, if you don't want to add to environment variables.

You can open Android Studio and go to: menu *Settings* → *Version Control* → *Git*. In the text box next to "Path to Git Executable" you will see "git.exe". Just give it a full path like so: C:\Users...............\git.exe

Comment: So the Android Studio PLUGINS: `Github plugin` & `GitHub Integration` on windows do not work without a Github program also installed?

Answer (score 4):

[Click here to download git](http://git-scm.com/downloads)

If you use Ubuntu
then write this command **$ sudo apt-get install git**

Answer (score 4):

In **Windows**, After [installing](https://git-scm.com/downloads) Git, you can get the Git location by opening **Command Prompt** and typing: **where git**

The above command will show the location of Git.exe, just copy the location & paste it in Path to Git executable & press Test.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, install `git.exe` and give the install directory path 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local'. After installation paste 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Git\bin\git.exe' in **Path to Git executable** in the Android Studio settings.

Comment: My path for Windows is `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

Answer (score 1):

To find the path of executables in Ubuntu just open the terminal and type
**$ which git**

Mostly it will be in /usr/bin/git and now you can set this path in android studio

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

If you integrate git in your system and set executable link in android studio.

So i am Linux Os user i am using some step integration git

1. Open terminal- **alt+ctrl+t**
2. Type command- **sudo apt install git**
3. type your password and press enter.

After the installation process is done run command to get the path of your git

4. check executable file- **whereis git**
5. If You want to navigate to this link via terminal as well, following are the commands

**$cd /**
**$cd usr**
**$cd bin**
**$ls**

Open Files->**Settings**->**Plugins**->**git**
You will see the path to $whereis git**strong text**executables all you need to do is navigate to the path we received after executing **$whereis git** command and hit test you will get something like this
[image]

after that you will check Go to **VCS->Import Into Version Control**-> Now Share Project on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

on command prompt write "where git"
it will give the path of git. copy this path and paste in the android studio.
it worked for me.