# Configuring path to Git executable in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

While I was trying to configure Git in Android Studio I was prompted to set the path to the Git executable. I am working on Ubuntu. How can I set this path?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427393/3020568

Comment: That SO answer is regarding windows. Am working in ubuntu...any changes?

Answer (score 2):

Close Android Studio, and run `sudo apt-get install git` from a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>). When it finishes, run Android Studio again.