# Cannot use git in Android Studio's terminal

Tags: android, git, terminal

Like my title, I cannot use git in intergrated terminal in Android Studio, although I added Path in Enviroment Variable. Please tell me why?

Thanks everybody for your help, after restarting windows, I used git command in terminal :D

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427393/6309 help?

Comment: please explain how did you try to use the git. Is it already a git repository?

Comment: I can use git by VCS -> Commit Changes, but i don't know why I cannot use git command in terminal in androdi studio (not terminal git bash in Windows). Sorry, i cannot post the image because I  don't have enough my reputation.

Comment: I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd" to my path in Enviroment Variables

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, and I restarted windows too :3

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**File** >> **Settings** >> **Version Control** >> **Git** >> Click on **Test** to see if the Test is successful, if not you have to adjust the path which includes git.

Probably you need to change also **cmd.exe**. Go to Settings, search terminal and include the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

Comment: I can push my project to github by the way using VCS-> Commit Changes but I cannot use git command (such as git add .) in terminal in android studio  (not terminal git bash in Windows)

Comment: So VCS basically works? And adding via the GUI works also? Check maybe in the Settings under "Path Variables" and set the path to git there again.