# Git Bash not recognized android command

Tags: android, git, bash, environment-variables, git-bash

[print_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFoAl.png)

Hi, I download android studio, and add enviroment variables to PATH (look print screen).
When i open CMD and use command ADROID is all OK, but when i use this command on Git Bash it doesn't work. 
bash: android: command not found.

I use win7 home premium 64 bit system
What I should do? I installed Git-2.13.1-64-bit

Android.bat working on git bash, what i have to do to start working android (without bat). Can I config this somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

in Android Studio Go to File > other Settings > Default setting> version control > git

and then define path to execute your git

Comment: and for windows take a look at this:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154497/cannot-use-git-in-android-studios-terminal