# Trying to use GitKraken with Android Studio but running into "cant start git.exe" error

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I first installed 'GitKraken' and cloned a repo into a directory. Now I downloaded 'Android Studio' and went to the same folder and clicked on "build.gradle" which I normally do if I want to build a project.

But I keep getting an error saying 'cant start git.exe' and when I click it, it takes me to a settings menu which asks me to provided a Path to a git executable.

I dont really understand what is causing this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Git kraken uses its own embedded version of git. You should [install git as well](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Then look for the git.exe and configure it into Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

As mention in the [GitKraken FAQ](https://www.gitkraken.com/faq)

> Unlike other Git GUI clients, GitKraken is not a front-end GUI for your command line; no Git tools are required. It works directly with your repositories with no dependencies, which means a separate Git installation isn’t even required.
>   Because of this, we currently do not offer direct integration between GitKraken and the CLI.

So, uncompress the [latest Git For Windows Portable edition](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) anywhere you want ([`PortableGit-2.11.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.11.1-64-bit.7z.exe))

Then you can [refer to this Git from your Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25427150/6309), as commented, and illustrated in [this article](http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial).

[image: http://user-image.logdown.io/user/756/blog/753/post/159805/aW22jGw0QgO4H5wlqRBd_git%20tool%20test.PNG]